# Is "He's looking this way! Get away before he sees you!" correct?

Tags: word-choice

Is the sentence correct, or would I need to reword it as "He's starting to look this way! Get away before he sees you!" In my first sentence, the person is in the process of turning his head to look at the other person, but in another sentence such as "I am looking at the painting" the object has already entered the person's vision and he is not turning his head.

Comment: It's fine. *Looking* is not the same as *seeing*. The statement, *He is looking this way*, leaves room for the possibility that he has not yet *seen*.

Comment: This applies for verbs such as eating and drinking as well right? For example, does it mean that a sentence like "'Hi,'I said while drinking the coffee I had just prepared" can mean that the statement was said before the coffee entered his body and was said while raising the mug to his lips?

Comment: No problem. You could theoretically break the acts of eating or drinking into a half dozen process actions and some of them might happen before anything actually enters your mouth. In the coupling of your original question, *looking this way* can be a process action of *seeing you*.

Comment: @ScotM There's a perceptional difference between the OP and you :) The way you are seeing the question is not quite what the OP means. At least that's how I see it.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, @Kris. I saw the same divergence of perception, and my comments were intended to help Joe recognize his ***acceptable*** meaning of *look = see*, without assuming that it was a ***necessary*** meaning. If he is *looking this way* for his parked car, he might not *see* me standing right there in front of him. *Looking* **can** be the same as *seeing*, as Joe rightly pointed out, but it is not **always** the same as *seeing*. Looking at the conversation again, I can see that I didn't drive that point all the way home.

Comment: @ScotM Let me clarify: I don't think it's anything about looking vs seeing at all.

Comment: As in *looking this way* is a metonym for *turning this way*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *looking* **can** indeed serve as a substitute for "starting to look/ about to look/ going to look" -- so you can say "He is looking this way" when you actually mean "He is going to look this way any moment now."

---

*meta:* I may edit in more details in support of the statement if I find something useful and reliable.